# cocoapods Framework file not found after installing github repo pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

So i'm trying to user this pod for my project:

https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu

However, after I install the podfile and try to build my app, I get tons of errors for the target but two of them stood out, however I cannot find a proper solution for this error:

[image: ditto error, can't get real path source]

[image: can't find a file from the framework in my DerivedData directory]

Im opening the .xcworkspace file so I'm sure that's not the issue.

I also tried setting "Buid Active Architecture Only" to 'NO'

I tried using pods deintegrate as well and then re running pod install but that also didn't fix the error.

pls help, I've gone through so many solutions regarding these errors but none have this weird problem of a file from the framework missing.

Comment: 1. Quit Xcode
2. Restart the System
3. Select Xcode -> Preferences. 
This will open a pop-up window. Select 'Locations'. In Locations, you will see 'Derived Data'. Click on the arrow icon right next to the path.
This will open a folder containing 'Derived Data', delete it.
4. Clean the Product and Run

Comment: I tried those instructions and it didn't work then I tried removing on terminal and still no luck, the directory keeps remaking itself and project still gets same error